# Slow Query- pivoting causes the issue

Tags: sql, oracle11g, aggregate

I have a query that takes around 4 minutes to run and really need to improve on this. I'm basically pivoting the data into columns. Any idea how I can improve this query? I am mostly joining on indexes. It is the aggregates that is causing the issues

Are there better ways of pivoting the data like this?

```
SELECT
    SKU.SKUIDX,
    CTYPE_STYLE.ARRCZIDX ARRCZ,
    MAX(IMPCOST.PURRATE) AS PURRATE,
    MAX(IMPCOST.PURCURR) AS PURCURR,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Purchase Cost' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS PURCHASE_COST,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Trim Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS TRIM_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Hanger Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS HANGER_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Duty Rate' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS DUTY_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Duty Fees' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS DUTY_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Freight Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS FREIGHT_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Agent Rate' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS AGENT_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Agent Fees' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS AGENT_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Clearance Rate' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS CLEARANCE_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Clearance Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS CLEARANCE_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Finance Rate' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS FINANCE_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Finance Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS FINANCE_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Fabric Testing Rate' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS FABRIC_TESTING_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Fabric Testing Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS FABRIC_TESTING_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'PickPack Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS PICK_PACK_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Local Processing Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS LOCAL_PROCESSING_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Rework Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS REWORK_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Wastage Rate' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS WASTAGE_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Wastage Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS WASTAGE_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Total Landed Cost' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS TOTAL_LANDED_COST,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Wholesale Price' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS WHOLESALE_PRICE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'First Margin%' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS FIRST_MARGIN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Royalty Rate' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS ROYALTY_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Royalty Fee' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS ROYALTY_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Second Margin%' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS SECOND_MARGIN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'CODB %' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS CODB_RATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'CODB' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS CODB_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN COSTFORM.DESCRIP = 'Third Margin%' THEN CTYPE_COSTSHT.COST ELSE NULL END) AS THIRD_MARGIN
  FROM
    AP21.SKU
  INNER JOIN
    AP21.IMPCOST_CLR ON
    IMPCOST_CLR.CLRIDX = SKU.CLRIDX
  INNER JOIN
    AP21.CLR ON
    CLR.CLRIDX = IMPCOST_CLR.CLRIDX
  INNER JOIN
    AP21.IMPCOST ON
    IMPCOST.ICIDX = IMPCOST_CLR.ICIDX
  INNER JOIN
    AP21.CTYPE_STYLE ON
    CTYPE_STYLE.STYLEIDX = CLR.STYLEIDX
    AND CTYPE_STYLE.CSIDX = IMPCOST.BSCSIDX
    AND CTYPE_STYLE.ACTIVE = 1
  INNER JOIN
    AP21.CTYPE_COSTSHT ON
    CTYPE_COSTSHT.CSIDX = CTYPE_STYLE.CSIDX
    AND CTYPE_COSTSHT.SKUIDX = SKU.SKUIDX
  INNER JOIN
    AP21.COSTLABL ON
    COSTLABL.COSTIDX = CTYPE_STYLE.COSTIDX
    AND COSTLABL.LABNUM = CTYPE_COSTSHT.LABNUM
  INNER JOIN
    AP21.COSTFORM ON
    COSTFORM.COSTIDX = CTYPE_STYLE.COSTIDX
    AND COSTFORM.POS = COSTLABL.POS
  WHERE
    SKU.ACTIVE = 1
  GROUP BY
    SKU.SKUIDX,
    CTYPE_STYLE.ARRCZIDX,
    IMPCOST.PURRATE,
    IMPCOST.PURCURR
```

My Explain Plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2077781369                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| Id  | Operation                            | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |               |     1 |   427 |    96   (4)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                       |               |     1 |   427 |    96   (4)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                       |               |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                      |               |     1 |   427 |    96   (4)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   4 |     VIEW                             | VW_GBC_37     |     1 |   416 |    94   (4)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   5 |      HASH GROUP BY                   |               |     1 |   107 |    94   (4)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                   |               |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                  |               |     1 |   107 |    93   (3)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                 |               |     1 |    85 |    90   (3)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                |               |     1 |    69 |    86   (3)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 10 |           HASH JOIN                  |               |     1 |    55 |    84   (3)| 00:00:02 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 11 |            HASH JOIN                 |               |  1122 | 50490 |    27   (4)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 12 |             HASH JOIN                |               |  1122 | 28050 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|  13 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL       | IMPCOST       |   776 | 12416 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|  14 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL       | IMPCOST_CLR   |  1122 | 10098 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 15 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CTYPE_STYLE   |  8121 |   158K|    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|  16 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL         | CLR           | 17469 |   170K|    56   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 17 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SKU           |     4 |    56 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 18 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SKU2IDX       |     4 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|  19 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | CTYPE_COSTSHT |     1 |    16 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 20 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN           | SYS_C006104   |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 21 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN             | CF1IDX        |    19 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|  22 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | COSTFORM      |     3 |    66 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 23 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | SYS_C006080   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
|* 24 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | COSTLABL      |     1 |    11 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

10 - access("CLR"."CLRIDX"="IMPCOST_CLR"."CLRIDX" AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
"CTYPE_STYLE"."STYLEIDX"="CLR"."STYLEIDX")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
11 - access("CTYPE_STYLE"."CSIDX"="IMPCOST"."BSCSIDX")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
12 - access("IMPCOST"."ICIDX"="IMPCOST_CLR"."ICIDX")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
15 - filter("CTYPE_STYLE"."ACTIVE"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
17 - filter("SKU"."ACTIVE"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
18 - access("IMPCOST_CLR"."CLRIDX"="SKU"."CLRIDX")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
20 - access("CTYPE_COSTSHT"."CSIDX"="CTYPE_STYLE"."CSIDX" AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"CTYPE_COSTSHT"."SKUIDX"="SKU"."SKUIDX")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
filter("CTYPE_COSTSHT"."SKUIDX"="SKU"."SKUIDX")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
21 - access("COSTFORM"."COSTIDX"="CTYPE_STYLE"."COSTIDX")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
23 - access("COSTLABL"."COSTIDX"="ITEM_2" AND "ITEM_3"="COSTLABL"."POS")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
filter("ITEM_3"="COSTLABL"."POS")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
24 - filter("COSTLABL"."LABNUM"="ITEM_1")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

 49 rows selected
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?  What does the explain plan say for the query?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  I believe some of them may have a `PIVOT()` method, though I've not used it myself...

Comment: I just added the explain plan. I really have to learn how to read these! @Clockwork-Muse, version 11g